# Magento 2 hide side bar if customer not logged in

Tags: magento-2.1, category, price, sidebar

I want to hide the price side bar if the customer is not logged in on the product category list page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy **view.phtml** file from

```
vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_LayeredNavigation/templates/layer/view.phtml
```

and override it in your theme.

Add below code just before

`<div data-role="collapsible" class="filter-options-item">`

```
<?php if($filter->getName() == 'Price'){
    if ($helper->isLoggedIn() == false) {
        continue;
    }
} ?>
```

Add below **isLoggedIn function** to in your custom module helper with constructor argument.

```
public function __construct(
            Context $context,
            \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->httpContext = $httpContext;

    }

public function isLoggedIn()
    {


        $isLoggedIn = $this->httpContext->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);

        return $isLoggedIn;
    }
```

Now price filter only showing for login customer.

Let me know if you have any issue/concern from above.

Answer (score 0):

check loggedIn user

```
<?php


$ObjectManager= \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$context = $ObjectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context');
$isLoggedIn = $context->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);
//echo $isLoggedIn;

if ($isLoggedIn == 1){
?>

<?php $_menu = $block->getHtml(0, 'level-top', 'submenu'); ?>
<div class="mb-navigation vertical-menu d-none d-md-block">
    <div class="title"><span class="mbi mbi-menu"></span><span class="d-none d-md-block"><?= __("Categories") ?>
            <i class="mbi mbi-ios-arrow-down"></i></span></div>
    <div class="navigation" data-action="navigation">
        <ul class="smartmenu magebig-nav">
            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_menu; ?>
            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getChildHtml(); ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```